# Swing JButton: Icon above Text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can I create a JButton in Swing with the icon above the text?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

just do this:

```
    button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```