# How to put the label of a AbstractButton on the bottom of the Icon?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my code to set the label on the bottom of the button Icon.

```
m_button.setIcon(large);
m_button.setLabel(m_button.getName());
m_button.setVerticalTextPosition(m_button.BOTTOM);

m_button.setMargin(BUTTON_INSETS);
m_button.setSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
m_button.setSize(20, 20);
```

But the result is the below one.

[image]

How can I make it on the bottom of the icon?
As this:
[image]

Comment: As the second Image. The Label is exactly on the bottom of the Icon.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354866/swing-jbutton-icon-above-text It uses SwingConstants.BOTTOM and also establishes horizontal position.

Comment: And `setLabel` is deprecated, try `setText` .

Comment: @Berger Thanks. I was googling for the javadoc to link :-) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setLabel(java.lang.String)

Comment: So, if I set the Text for the button same as the Label here, will it work?

Comment: I will try and update

Comment: @Saj setLabel and setText will do the same. Try with the solution linked. Use SwingConstants and setHorizontalTextPosition.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the code: m_button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
But the same result

Comment: And setting both Vertical and Horizontal? THAT is the solution linked.

Comment: @RubioRic Thank you very much. I was not setting the Horizontal Text Position. You save my day.

Comment: @Saj Glad to help. Remember to upvote the linked answer. It's not mine, but anyway. :-)

Comment: Sure. Will do the same. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set *both* horizontal and vertical text positions:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Test", icon);
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
```